# How to prove piecewise defined function is integrable?

Tags: real-analysis

Here's the question:

Define the function f(x)=1 if x=1/n and f(x)=4 for all other values of x.

You may assume that a function with a finite number of finite discontinuities is integrable.

Even though this function has an infinite number of disconitinuities on the interval [0,1], prove that it is integrable on [0,1]

I've tried thinking about upper and lower sums and partitions, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that we can use is that the partitions for the upper and lower sums do not to be of uniform width.

Fix $\varepsilon>0$, with $\varepsilon<1$. Then we can choose a partition $X=\{x_j\}$ such that for each $n$ there exists $j$ with $x_j<\frac1n<x_{j+1}$ and $x_{j+1}-x_j<\varepsilon/2^n$.

Then the contribution of the intervals containing the $1/n$ to the upper and lower sums will be less than $\varepsilon$.